# AVERAGEIF based on multiple columns in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following Stylesheet:

```
       A   |   B
1 | Name 1 | Value 1
2 | Name 2 | Value 2
3 | Name 2 | Value 3
4 | Name 3 | Value 4
```

I'd like to do an average value of the lowest value for each name. So here the average would be on values of row 1 2 and 4 if `Value 2 < Value 4`.

That seems a bit complex so I tried an other approach: do the average value of the first entry for each name. I'd just have to order those fields to get the result I want. I tried the following: `AVERAGEIF(A:A,"<>INDIRECT(""A""&(ROW()-1))", B:B)` but that doesn't seem to work and it takes all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(QUERY({A1:B4},"select Col1, min(Col2) group by Col1", 0),"select Col2"))
```

and evarage doesn't look for strings, so this should work too:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY({A1:B4},"select Col1, min(Col2) group by Col1", 0))
```

Comment: Awesome! And yes, second solution also works. Thanks alot